How to change the height of only select rows in Antd table?
I'm using Antd with React. I also have tailwind css in the project.
In the dataSource of <Table/>, I'm giving items where where some of them contain the key is_special. I want to reduce/set a different height to those rows with the keys is_special.

tried rowClassName ?

To customize the row height based on the is_special key in the dataSource of an Ant Design , you can use the rowClassName prop. This prop allows you to apply custom class names to each row, which you can then style using Tailwind CSS.
Here's a step-by-step approach:
Define a custom row class: Use the rowClassName function to add a custom class to rows where is_special is true.
Apply Tailwind CSS styles: Use Tailwind's utility classes to control the row height.


import React from 'react';
import { Table } from 'antd';

// Sample dataSource
const dataSource = [
  {
    key: '1',
    name: 'John Brown',
    age: 32,
    address: 'New York No. 1 Lake Park',
    is_special: true,
  },
  {
    key: '2',
    name: 'Jim Green',
    age: 42,
    address: 'London No. 1 Lake Park',
    is_special: false,
  },
  // More data...
];

// Define columns
const columns = [
  {
    title: 'Name',
    dataIndex: 'name',
    key: 'name',
  },
  {
    title: 'Age',
    dataIndex: 'age',
    key: 'age',
  },
  {
    title: 'Address',
    dataIndex: 'address',
    key: 'address',
  },
];

const CustomTable = () => {
  return (
    <Table
      dataSource={dataSource}
      columns={columns}
      rowClassName={(record) => (record.is_special ? 'special-row' : '')}
    />
  );
};

export default CustomTable;
/* styles.css */
.special-row {
  @apply h-10; /* Example: set a specific height for special rows */
}



Explanation
rowClassName: This prop takes a function that returns a class name based on the current row's data (record). If is_special is true, it returns 'special-row', otherwise an empty string.
Tailwind CSS: Use Tailwind's @apply directive to apply utility classes to the custom class. In this case, h-10 sets the row height. Adjust the height as needed for your design.
